# Checking if a user defined item exists in a HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

Im making a class called Book which contains the books name and price. If i insert those data into a HashSet, how would be i able to check if a book exists in that HashSet by only searching for the book name?

I currently have:

```
public Book(String name, double price){
   this.name = name;
   this.price = price;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
   HashSet<Book> hs = new HashSet<Book>();
   Book book1 = new Book("Plant Book", 19.99);
   Book book2 = new Book("Garden Book", 24.99);
   Book book3 = new Book("Cook Book", 14.99);
   
   hs.add(book1);
   hs.add(book2);
   hs.add(book3);

   System.out.println(hs.contains("Plant Book")); //I want this to return true
}
```

So how would i be able to search for Plant Book in this HashSet?

Comment: iterate over the content of the set, or use a stream, and check the name until either you've reached the end, or have found a match

Comment: Note: Your class `Book` should implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` for it to be properly used in a hash-based collection such as `HashSet`.

Comment: @Jesper that will only allow to see if a book exists with the same name and price, or the price is not part of equality which also doesn't sound great.

Comment: `"Plant Book"` won't be equal to `new Book("Plant Book", 19.99);`. I assume you're looking for a `Map<String, Book>` instead. This would then become: `map.put("Plant Book", new Book("Plant Book", 19.99));` and `map.get("Plant Book")` (if you're only interested in existence of the entry you can check for null or just use `containsKey()`).

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks that works. Should i use the same concept for removing a book name? Just to iterate through?

Answer (score 4):

Using a stream can make life quite easy sometimes:

```
hs.stream().anyMatch(book -> "Plant book".equals(book.getName()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely recommend implementing `equals` and `hashCode` for the class that will be added to the HashSet since that will solve the use case of not allowing "similar" items to be added to the HashSet.

For your requirements, iterating over the items and checking for the name is likely the best thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in the comments by [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas), it seems a map would better suit your requirements.   Here I am using a `record` to demonstrate.

Everything is pretty much the same except for the methods used for accessing and testing a map.

```
record Book(String getName, double getPrice){}

Map<String, Book> hmap = new HashMap<>();
Book book1 = new Book("Plant Book", 19.99);
Book book2 = new Book("Garden Book", 24.99);
Book book3 = new Book("Cook Book", 14.99);

// using put to enter the name and Book instance
hmap.put(book1.getName(),book1);
hmap.put(book2.getName(),book2);
hmap.put(book3.getName(),book3);

// here using containsKey for the check
String name = "Plant Book";
if (hmap.containsKey(name)) {
       System.out.println(hmap.get(name));
}
```

prints

```
Book[getName=Plant Book, getPrice=19.99]
```

You can also put the keys in `lowercase` or `uppercase` names and then just use the required case names for checking and retrieval.

```
hmap.put(book.getName().toLowerCase(), book);
```